# Laravel config file of a module

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to get the keys of a file inside the config of a module. I created `User` module using [nWidart](https://nwidart.com/) package. This is the `registerConfig` function

```
protected function registerConfig()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../Config/config.php' => config_path('user.php'),
    ], 'config');
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(
        __DIR__.'/../Config/config.php', 'user'
    );
}
```

I created a file named `menu.php` that returns an array with a key `items`, then tried this

```
dd(config('user::config.name'))
dd(config('user::menu.items'))
```

They both return null. I also tried `php artisan vendor-publish` of `UserServiceProvider` but it still returns null. How can I return the keys?

**update**

If I simply do: `config()` I get a full array of the config arrays and can see my package config file there. But the `menu` config file is not in there

Comment: `config("user.name")` . You need to use publishes in boot method and mergeConfigFrom in register method of your service provider.

Comment: @Bugfixer `config("config.name")` and  `config("user.name")` both return the result. But I can't get the menu keys that are in a separate file. The configuration for menu is in `menu.php` not `config.php`

Comment: how menu.php is called in service provider. it need to be called in service provider.

Comment: @Bugfixer the `registerConfig` is in the question. I didn't call it in there! How can I do it?

Comment: `config('menu.items')` check if this works ? and check if menu.php and config.php are in same folder.

Comment: @Bugfixer No it is null

Comment: you can put second config(menu.php) in in config folder on root. and can access it directly.

Comment: @Bugfixer every module must have its own menu file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180662/discussion-between-bugfixer-and-drupalist).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Your serviceProvider, register method.

```
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(
        __DIR__ . '/../config/master.php',
        'master'
    );

    // Merge configs
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(
        __DIR__ . '/../config/slave.php',
        'slave'
    );
```

Create two files inside config folder
slave.php

```
    <?php
return [
    'menu' => [
        'OP1',
        'OP2',
        'OP3',
        'OP4',
    ]
];
```

master.php
    //any other config you want to load

Run php artisan config:cache

and use

> dd(config('slave.menu'));
>   dd(config('master.XXX'));

This will output

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => "OP1"
  1 => "OP2"
  2 => "OP3"
  3 => "OP4"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return [
'name' => 'Blog',
'en_name'=>'Blog',
'icon'=>'comment',
'color1'=>'EF6F6C',
'color2'=>'EF6F6C',
'route'=>'blog',
'disable' => false,

'subs'=>[
    ['name'=>'All Posts','route'=>'blog/list'],
    ['name'=>'All Categories','route'=>'category/list']
]
```

];

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please elaborate what this configuration does and how it helps to solve the original problem. Code-only answers are not considered as good quality in StackOverflow. Thanks!